# Create Unique MYSQL Primary Key Where Only Part Of is Incremntal

Tags: php, mysql, unique, primary-key

In one of my mysql table, I need to generate the primary key field which is 15 digit in length.

```
Structure is 2+2+2+2+2+5 as ex: 010101010100001.
```

First 10 Digit values comes from five 2 digit form/input fields and last 5 character is unique and incremental. So, whenever a form/data is submitted that value will be increased.

now how can I achieve that?

I think of following method but thinking of 2 issue:

`First use select query to get the last used id/number. Then add +1 to it.`**

**Issue-1:**

For this I have to make 2 query 1 for select and 1 for update, but I think there is much better way than this?

**Issue-2:**

What if multiple like hundreds/thousands of users submit the form at the very same time? how can I make sure it will be unique and wont cause a db error?

any suggestion/idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been told it has to be a primary key or do you think a primary key is the only way to guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes sir, it has to be primary key.

Comment: @Zakir_SZH Please edit your question to include a description/explanation on why you want to create such a complicated primary key for your table? Why do you want it to be the primary key and not just a normal column with a UNIQUE index? Why do you not use a normal `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column, which is the common way to create a primary key for a table?

Comment: @Progman, ok, then sir, even for a unique key how can i achieve that without any chance of duplicate key/index?

Answer (score 0):

Having a UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY ensures that you cannot have any duplicate entries in the database. You will get an error message from MySQL if you try to create a duplicate entry. So you don't need to check for duplicates, MySQL will do so for you. However you have to check for error messages and react accordingly by changing the value like adding `+1` on it, depending on your requirements.